Error 91 when activating newly opened Workbook
I'm running into this error:

Run-time error 91 Object Variable or With block variable not set

When I attempt to activate a Workbook that was opened by the Set statement.
The code works fine to open the indicated Workbooks, but when it reached the point where I try to Activate or Select or Edit the Workbook, the error populates. One of the files being opened is a csv, the other is xlsx, either way the Workbook will not activate and sends an error. Do I need to define the variable again, and if so, how? The name is dynamic and the same for both files being opened except for the file type.
Dim i As Integer
        For i = 2 To .Range.Rows.Count
            ' Retrieve current row's values
            active = Trim(.Range(i, 2).Value2)
            reportName = Trim(.Range(i, 3).Value2)
            
            If active Then
            Dim wbSource As Workbook
            Dim wbDest As Workbook
            Set wbSource = OpenwbSource(reportName)
            Set wbDest = OpenwbDest(reportName)
            
            wbSource.Activate  ' (Error 91)
            wbDest.Activate ' (Error 91) (whichever is first causes the error)
            ' The code continues... from here I would copy data from csv to xlsx file and edit...

            End If
            Next i
        End With
End Sub

Public Function OpenwbSource(reportName As String) As Workbook

    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(PathSource & reportName & ".csv")

    Exit Function

End Function

Public Function OpenwbDest(reportName As String) As Workbook
    
    
    Dim wbDest As Workbook
    Set wbDest = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Templates\" & reportName & ".xlsx")
    
    
    Exit Function

End Function

I've tried using another With statement. I've tried re-defining the workbook.

Where is the beginning of your With statement? It appears to be missing. Once you figure that out, put a breakpoint on .Range(i, 3).Value2 and check that value to see if it's what you expect when you run it.

Your function OpenwbSource doesn't return anything.  You need Set OpenwbSource = Workbooks.Open(...)

Also this is an Overkill of using a function to open a workbook. I would rather create 2 path constants and open the workbook in the Main Sub...

braX The beginning of the With statement was just before the Dim i As Integer, I didn't copy it over. And Siddharth, it is overkill but the Functions will eventually be used to do more than what is currently indicated.

To focus on only the immediate problem you ask about, as indicated by others, the problem is that OpenwbSource() doesn't return a Workbook. This is because you Set the value into a variable wbSource but that is then unused (the same problem with OpenwbDest()). As such, the Function will then return Nothing.
Note that the wbSource in OpenwbSource() is declared locally (ie within the Function) and, as such, is entirely separate from the wbSource declared in the first procedure in the code that you provide (that is missing its declaration ie its line with Sub or Function).
To return a non-Nothing value from your Function, you must assign a value to the Function ... in the case of your two functions:
Public Function OpenwbSource(reportName As String) As Workbook
    Set OpenwbSource = Workbooks.Open(PathSource & reportName & ".csv")
End Function

Public Function OpenwbDest(reportName As String) As Workbook
    Set OpenwbDest = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Templates\" & reportName & ".xlsx")
End Function

To learn more about Functions, see Function statement. And for how to return values from them, see the section starting "To return a value from a function, assign the value to the function name ...".
I think there are potentially other problems with your code ... please raise a separate question if you then experience other problems.
